# what is the sbt repository

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm getting started with scala word (coming from java) 

I'm trying to find some dependencies to add to my build.sbt, however, I cannot find an sbt repository (like mvn repo ), I tried this [one](https://repo.scala-sbt.org/) but It doesn't work,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find `sbt` dependencies in maven repository itself. If there is a sbt dependency available for a given library  or pacakge, then it will be mentioned like [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.12/2.5.20) under the `SBT` tab.

Comment: ok, I find it, thak you, I thought that there is a specific repo for scala